# How can I convert daily snapshots to an effective date range in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am attempting to write a procedure that will scale down a very large table by converting each daily record with the same data into a single record with an effective date range. For the sake of illustration, here is a simplified version of my data:

```
user_id   value     row_start_date          row_end_date
-------   -----     --------------          ------------
ABC123      5       6/2/2018 4:01:35 PM     6/3/2018 4:01:44 PM
ABC123      5       6/3/2018 4:01:35 PM     6/4/2018 4:01:44 PM
ABC123      6       6/4/2018 4:01:45 PM     6/5/2018 4:01:11 PM
ABC123      6       6/5/2018 4:01:45 PM     6/6/2018 4:01:11 PM
ABC123      5       6/6/2018 4:01:12 PM     6/7/2018 4:01:56 PM
ABC123      5       6/7/2018 4:01:12 PM     6/8/2018 4:01:56 PM
ABC123      5       6/8/2018 4:01:12 PM     6/9/2018 4:01:56 PM
```

My query resembles this one:

```
select 
    user_id
    , value
    , min(row_start_date) as row_start_date
    , max(row_end_date) as row_end_date
from
    table1
group by
    user_id
    , value
```

However, it is unable to account for the minor break when the value changed to 6 and then back to 5

```
user_id   value     row_start_date          row_end_date
-------   -----     --------------          ------------
ABC123      5       6/2/2018 4:01:35 PM     6/9/2018 4:01:56 PM
ABC123      6       6/4/2018 4:01:45 PM     6/6/2018 4:01:11 PM
```

How can I get my query to produce the output below?

```
user_id   value     row_start_date          row_end_date
-------   -----     --------------          ------------
ABC123      5       6/2/2018 4:01:35 PM     6/4/2018 4:01:44 PM
ABC123      6       6/4/2018 4:01:45 PM     6/6/2018 4:01:11 PM
ABC123      5       6/6/2018 4:01:12 PM     6/9/2018 4:01:56 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the provided data and expected answer, simple group by will do just fine:

```
select * from table1 group by user_id, value, rows_start_date
```

If you want to take min and max dates as in your query from each continuous block with the same value, then you can use [match_recognize](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8957):

```
select *
from table1 match_recognize (
  partition by
    user_id
  order by
    row_start_date
  measures
    init.value as value,
    init.row_start_date as row_start_date,
    max(row_end_date) as row_end_date
  one row per match
  pattern (init same_value*)
  define
    same_value as value = prev(value)
)
```

Using this query you'll partition the dataset by user_id, order by row_start_date and then try to find a set of rows such that they have the same value as the first row. If you find such set, you'll output value and row_start_date from the first row and max(row_end_date) from the whole set.

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  If you have no gaps in the dates, you can simply use the difference of row numbers technique:

```
select user_id, value,
       min(row_start_date) as row_start_date
       max(row_end_date) as row_end_date
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_idorder by row_start_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, value order by row_start_date) as seqnum_2
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
group by user_id, value, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Gordon. Unfortunately, there are some gaps in the dates on my table, but I may be able to leverage this technique if I clean up beforehand.